# How to remove the warning: Rcpp/DataFrame.h:136:18: warning unused variable 'data'?

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I created an R package using RcppArmadillo from my Mac, and then built and installed it by doing the following:

```
Rcpp::compileAttributes()
devtools::build()
devtools::install()
```

However, I received several same warnings as below:

```
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:34:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:57:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/DataFrame.h:136:18: warning: unused variable 'data' [-Wunused-variable]
            SEXP data = Parent::get__();
                 ^
1 warning generated.
```

The package works fine although there are warnings during installation. Does anyone know how I can get rid of these warnings?

(I tried the answer here: [Wunused-variable errors in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234164/wunused-variable-errors-in-rcpp), but I still got the warnings.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My previous (generic) [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234164/wunused-variable-errors-in-rcpp) (which you already referenced in your question) is still valid: Add the flag to `CXXFLAGS` (and maybe also `CXX11FLAGS`).

Alternatively, you can install *an updated Rcpp version* from the [Rcpp Drat](http://rcppcore.github.io/drat/) repo via

```
install.packages("Rcpp", repos="https://rcppcore.github.io/drat")
```

to get an Rcpp version with this fixes, and some other new versions. These fix will eventually make it into the CRAN version.

*Edit:* Here is a link to relevant announcement to the [Rcpp mailing list](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2021-January/010575.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! The ```CXX11FLAGS``` one solved the issue.

Comment: You're welcome!  R itself controls these, and it's a bit tricky that values set for `CXXFLAGS` do not automagically promote to `CXX11FLAGS` (and same for C++14, C++17, ...)   But at least now you know :)   Also, of course: "warnings" are just "warnings", as annoying as they are. If you are _very_ confident in what you are doing you can also .... edit the header file :)